# mirror site in subfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have a site in a cpanel subfolder but cpanel does not allow me to change the document root of the main domain hence i need to be able to mirror the site that is currently in a sub folder (dev) when im viewing the main domain

domain.com

yet i will be actually viewing

domain.com/dev

without a redirect !

hence when i view

domain.com/sales.html

we will actually be seeing

domain.com/dev/sales.html

ive tried everything on cpanel and just not possible

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty straight forward, actually... If you really "tried everything", as you wrote and things won't work as demonstrated in thousands of answers here, then  most likely the rewriting is not the actual issue... Maybe the rewriting modules is not loaded at all into your http server? Or not enabled for your site? Is the interpretation of dynamic configuration files enabled at all? Did you check that? *How?*

That aside here is the simple rule hat implements what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/dev/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /dev/$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).